# puppet installation error -enable repo

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I am Enabling the official Puppet Labs collection repository with this command:

when i try to do :

sudo rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-7.noarch.rpm

error:

```
Retrieving http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-7.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.4CilbA: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 4bd6ec30: NOKEY
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
        file /etc/yum.repos.d/puppetlabs.repo from install of puppetlabs-release-7-12.noarch conflicts with file from package puppetlabs-release-6-12.noarch
```

does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Note that this repository is old and only contains Puppet 3! Puppet 4 repo instructions are at https://docs.puppet.com/guides/puppetlabs_package_repositories.html#using-puppet-collections

Comment: Are you on a EL6 or EL7 system?

Comment: [root@ip-10-********** /]# cat /etc/*{release,version}
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2016.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2016.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2016.03"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.03

Comment: how to tell whether its a EL6 or EL7 system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

executing the below comand  solved this error:

```
[root@ip-10-****/]# rpm -qa | grep puppetlabs-release
puppetlabs-release-6-12.noarch
[root@ip-10-****/]# rpm -e puppetlabs-release-6-12.noarch
```